# DataTable updating some columns using primary key

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a dataTable defined in a class thus:

```
Public Shared Positions As DataTable
```

When my main form loads I create the structure for the DataTable like so:

```
Function createTable()
    ' Function to create datatable structure
    Dim table As New DataTable

    ' Define primary key
    Dim keys(0) As DataColumn
    Dim keyColumn As New DataColumn()
    keyColumn.ColumnName = "hash"
    keys(0) = keyColumn

    ' Define columns
    table.Columns.Add(keyColumn)
    table.Columns.Add("PositionX", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("PositionY", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("PositionZ", GetType(String))

    return table
End Function
```

The values of PositionX, PositionY, and PositionZ change over time and I'd like to update them in the DataTable using the value of hash which is the primary key.

However, I just can't seem to get the syntax right.  This article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tat996zc.aspx) suggests that this approach would work:

```
Dim customerRow() As Data.DataRow
customerRow = DataSet1.Tables("Customers").Select("CustomerID = 'ALFKI'")

customerRow(0)("CompanyName") = "Updated Company Name"
customerRow(0)("City") = "Seattle"
```

But applying it to my code:

```
' Get the row containing this object
Dim resultRow() As Globals.Positions.DataRow
resultRow= Globals.Positions.Tables("Positions").Select("hash = '44DE43AB'")

resultRow(0)("PositionX") = 123456789
resultRow(0)("PositionY") = 123456789
```

Gives errors on the first two lines "Globals.Positions.DataRow not defined" and "Tables is not a member of DataTable".

What do I need to do in order to get the row containing the value of the primary key that I'm looking for so that I can update some of the column values ?

Comment: Will this stuff be going to a db?  There are a fair number of issues there.

Comment: No, this is just to hold the positions of the objects that I'm tracking in memory.  When I lose contact with them they will be removed after a certain time.

Comment: a) that will not compile under Option Strict - that function has no return type b) if X Y and Z are numeric, the columns ought not be string  c) we cant see a `Globals.Positions.DataRow` defined, but since DataRow is a Type I suspect you meant something else   d) A `DataTable` does not contain `Tables` so the second is about the same as (c)

Comment: Thanks.  a) how do I go about adding a type ?  Since each column has a type, do I need one for the table ?  b) true, X, Y and Z could be a numeric type, c & d) I was working from the example linked above, trying to adapt the code in that example so far unsucessfully

Comment: PS I'm trying to use the primary key in order to avoid having to loop through all the rows in my DataTable as speed is of the essence in this application.

Comment: *That* MSDN example doesnt quite apply to what you are doing - they are starting with a strongly typed DataSet.  I suspect a Class for the X-Y-Z and a collection would be quicker than rifling thru a DataTable.  A collection of them and a little linq would likely be easier too

Comment: OK, thanks.  I've already tried doing this as a Structure (consumed vast amounts of RAM),  quickly throwing the data into a DataGridView (too slow) and as a two-dimensional array (kept getting out of bounds errors).  I'll have a look at doing it as a class tomorrow ...

Comment: How many items are you talking about?

Comment: Dim resultRow() As DataRow = table.Rows().Select("hash = '44DE43AB'")

resultRow(0)("PositionX") = 123456789

resultRow(0)("PositionY") = 123456789

Comment: @TonyDong Thanks - however, table is not defined in the routine where I'm updating the values contained within the dataset.  The object is defined globally and then the structure is defined when the form loads like this: Globals.Positions = Parser.createTable().  Changing the line to Globals.Positions.Rows().Select("hash ='44DE43AB'") gives "Select is not a member of DataRowCollection"

Comment: Is there any reason for using DataTable instead of Dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps have a property in the class for the DataTable, set it up, load data. Have a method to find and set values in a row e.g.

```
Public Class Demo1
    Public Property DataTable As DataTable
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Fire off create and load tabe
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()
        CreateTable()
        LoadData()
    End Sub
    Public Sub CreateTable()
        DataTable = New DataTable
        DataTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "hash", .DataType = GetType(String)})
        DataTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "PositionX", .DataType = GetType(String)})
        DataTable.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {DataTable.Columns("hash")}

    End Sub
    Public Sub LoadData()
        DataTable.Rows.Add(New Object() {"22DE43AS"})
        DataTable.Rows.Add(New Object() {"44DE43AB"})
        DataTable.Rows.Add(New Object() {"33DE43AW"})
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Simple demo to find and update a row
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="hash"></param>
    ''' <param name="PositionX"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public Function SetItem(ByVal hash As String, PositionX As String) As Boolean
        Dim result As DataRow() = DataTable.Select($"hash = '{hash}'")
        If result.Count > 0 Then
            result.First.SetField(Of String)("PositionX", PositionX)
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Demo

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim demo As New Demo1
    If demo.SetItem("44DE43AB", "new value") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Success")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Failed")
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: That's great Karen your example is exactly what I needed.  I've rewritten my code to allow me to add, update and remove items and it appears to be working.  I just need to figure out how to pull a list of all data out of the datatable.  Thank you again !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Dictionary` instead:

```
Class Point3D
    Public X, Y, Z As Integer
End Class

Sub test()
    Dim Positions As New Dictionary(Of String, Point3D)         ' create
    Positions("44DE43AB") = New Point3D With {.X = 1, .Y = 2}   ' add
    Positions("44DE43AB").Z = 3                                 ' edit
    Positions.Remove("44DE43AB")                                ' remove
End Sub
```